# "Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)" in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I am trying to update the file then getting error like:

> Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'designation'=>'required',
        'contact_ph'=>'required',
        'contact_email'=>'required',
        'featured'=>'mimes:jpeg,pdf,docx,png:5000',
    ]);

    $staff=Staff::find($id);

    if($request->hasFile('featured'))
    {
        $featured=$request->featured;
        $featured_new_name =time() .$featured->getClientOriginalName();
        $featured->move('uploads/srcpost', $featured_new_name);
        $staff->featured='uploads/srcposts/'. $featured_new_name;
    }

    $staff->name=$request=name;
    $staff->designation=$request=designation;
    $staff->ordering=$request=ordering;

    $staff->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Check your lines starting from $staff->name=$request=name;                               It should be $request->name or $request->get('name');

Comment: thank for your answer @pascalzoet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few ways in which you could retrieve variables from `$request` are shown below:

```
$request->name;
$request->get('name');
$request->input('name');
```

Therefore, for your code to execute correctly.

replace your code:

```
 $staff->name=$request=name;
 $staff->designation=$request=designation;
 $staff->ordering=$request=ordering;
```

with the following:

```
$staff->name=$request->name;
$staff->designation=$request->designation;
$staff->ordering=$request->ordering;
```

Comment: yes thank you @dexter and can I ask another query here

Comment: where I have to mark as a correct, not getting option

Comment: My query is, I want to upload the pdf and have 4 coulumn and int this title, content, upload_pdf_file and content, I am able to upload the pdf file but when going on website only title and content showing and want to pdf file when click on title and content

Comment: thanks, I am new in this so not exact idea, I did now

Comment: I am trying to open pdf file that I have uploaded and when click on website it's showing file not found 404

Comment: <div class="entry-content">
  
       <a  target="_blank" href="{{$post->file}}">

       <p style="font-size: 18px;color: #468b10;"> 

        {{ $post->content }}</p></a>

                                        </div>

Comment: Controller

          public function store(Request $request)
    {
               $data = [

            'content'=>$request->content,

            'category_id'=>$request->category_id,

        ];



       

       if (request('file')) {

            $file = request('file');

            $file=$file_name::get($file);

            $file_name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->move('uploads/posts', $file_name);

            $data['file'] = 'uploads/posts/'.$file_name;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use of undefined constant ‘content’ - assumed '‘content’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\wamp64\www\amadotester\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)